# Can someone help resolve this warning message?

Tags: r, csv, message

So, I wrote this code in R:

```
#ANOVA to test for differences in average stomatal density among the four treatment groups, respectively 
# set working directory
setwd("~/Desktop/College/FALL 2020")

Stomata <- read.csv ("stomatathis.csv")
Stomata
```

As a result, this is what I got back:

```
> setwd("~/Desktop/College/FALL 2020")
> 
> Stomata <- read.csv ("stomatathis.csv")
Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'stomatathis.csv'
> Stomata
  treatment.group avg.stomatal.density
1         group 1             112.8200
2         group 2             116.5180
3         group 3             102.9299
4         group 4              94.5506
```

Could someone help me resolve the warning message in the output? I have attached the excel file I am using, so convert to .csv before implementing in R.

Comment: It seems like I can't attach the excel file, so I am inputting the data below.                                                               > Stomata
  treatment.group avg.stomatal.density
1         group 1             112.8200
2         group 2             116.5180
3         group 3             102.9299
4         group 4              94.5506

Comment: Your file likely just does not end with a new line character which is typically expected. It should be safe to ignore that warning. It's really only a problem because your file is exactly 5 lines long. If it were longer, you wouldn't get this message which is specifically trying to find the header.